# How to play notification audio file in Chrome WebExtension without user gesture?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a webextension for Google Chrome and I'm trying to implement a function that plays a sound effect to notify the user about updates on the background.js script.

```
    var sound = new Audio(browserContainer.runtime.getURL("audio/not.ogg"));
    sound.play();
```

The problem is that thanks to Chrome's policies, the audio cannot autoplay without some sort of user gesture. I receive the error "Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture."

How can I force Chrome to autoplay the notification sound without a user gesture? I know it is possible, because I've seen other extensions do this, like "Checker Plus for Gmail"

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding an `audio` HTML tag to the background page, like this:

**manifest.json**

```
"background":{"page":"background.html"}
```

**background.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <audio id="mysound" preload="auto" src="audio/not.ogg"></audio>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**background.js**

```
var sound = document.getElementById('mysound');
sound.play()
```